# Gaussian integral in condensed matter field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, condensed-matter

So i need to do the exercise in page 188 from Atland and Simon, "Electron-Phonon copuling". I could do the letter a, the problem is with letter b. I am not sure how to perform the integral to get rid of the phonons field.

Should i return to the $\vec{x}$ variables to do the integration? In such way that $\sum_q \rightarrow \int d^d x$ in the exponential?

I tried to do it (very sloppy, just to see if we get near the answer) with the $q$ variables instead, and the math was something like that:

$
    S_{\text{eff}}[\overline{\psi},\psi] = S_{\text{el}}[\overline{\psi},\psi] - \ln \left ( \int D[\overline{\phi},\phi] e^{-(S_{\text{ph}}[\overline{\phi},\phi] + S_{\text{el-ph}}[\overline{\psi},\psi,\overline{\phi},\phi])} \right )
$

So let's evaluate the following term

$
    (S_{\text{ph}}[\overline{\phi},\phi] + S_{\text{el-ph}}[\overline{\psi},\psi,\overline{\phi},\phi])
$

$
    \sum_{q,j} \bigg [  \left ( \overline{\phi}_{q,j} (-i \omega_n + \omega_q \right ) \phi_{q,j} + \frac{i \gamma q_j}{(2 m \omega_q)^{1/2}} \rho_q ( \phi_{q,j} + \overline{\phi}_{q,j} ) \bigg ]
$

Changing variables

$
    \phi_{q,j} + \overline{\phi}_{q,j} = A_{q,j} \\
    \phi_{q,j} = \phi_{q,j}
$

$
    \sum_{q,j} \bigg [  \left ( A_{q,j} - \phi_{q,j}) (-i \omega_n + \omega_q \right ) \phi_{q,j} + \frac{i \gamma q_j}{(2 m \omega_q)^{1/2}} \rho_q A_{q,j} \bigg ]
$

$
    \sum_{q,j} \bigg [ \phi_{q,j} ( i \omega_n - \omega_q ) \phi_{q,j} + \left ( A_{q,j} (-i \omega_n + \omega_q )  \right ) \phi_{q,j}  + \frac{i \gamma q_j}{(2 m \omega_q)^{1/2}} \rho_q A_{q,j} \bigg ]
$

So, performing the path integral first over $\phi$, we should get something like that

$
    \int D[\overline{\phi},\phi] e^{-S(...)} \propto \int DA ( i \omega_n - \omega_q )^{-1/2} \exp \bigg [ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{q,j}  A_{q,j} (-i \omega_n + \omega_q ) ( i \omega_n - \omega_q )^{-1}  A_{q,j} (-i \omega_n + \omega_q ) \bigg ] \exp [\frac{i \gamma q_j}{(2 m \omega_q)^{1/2}} \rho_q A_{q,j} ] 
$

$
    \propto \int DA ( i \omega_n - \omega_q )^{-1/2} \exp \bigg [ -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{q,j}  A_{q,j} (-i \omega_n + \omega_q ) A_{q,j} \bigg ] \exp [ \sum_{q,j} \frac{i \gamma q_j}{(2 m \omega_q)^{1/2}} \rho_q A_{q,j} ] 
$

Now performing over $A$, we get that

$
    \int D[\overline{\phi},\phi] e^{-(S_{\text{ph}}[\overline{\phi},\phi] + S_{\text{el-ph}}[\overline{\psi},\psi,\overline{\phi},\phi])} \propto ( i \omega_n - \omega_q )^{-1} \exp \bigg [ \sum_{q,j} \frac{1}{2} \frac{i \gamma q_j \rho_q}{(2 m \omega_q)^{1/2}} \frac{1}{\omega_q - i \omega_n} \frac{i \gamma q_j \rho_{q}}{(2 m \omega_q)^{1/2}} \bigg ] 
$

As i said, i am being veeeeeery sloppy, only to see where we get. If we take the $\ln$ of this

$
S ~ S_{\text{el}} - \bigg [ \sum_{q,j} \frac{1}{2} \frac{\gamma^2 q^2 \rho_q \rho_q}{(2 m \omega_q)} \bigg ] + \text{other terms}
$

Which is a little near the answer.

Am i following the right reasoning? I am a little confused on how to perform the path integral with the varaibles in the action being summed $\sum_{q,j}$, instead being integrated $\int d^d x d^d x'$